# View passwords stored in Nemo

Tags: password, nemo

I have a password stored on nemo for ssh://XXX the server is a new server and I told myself, I'll not be lazy and turn off password tomorrow... I can be lazy, but this is a first!

I have stored the servers password in nemos sftp password manager.

So, is it possible to view this password?

Comment: I'd guess, `nemo` or `nautilus` store their passwords in the keystore. Open `seahorse` to check.

Comment: Well that was easy. I had tried seahorse already, but could not see anything... oddly, this time all keys and types were displaying. Thank you for making me double check

Comment: It does, but I do not think anybody would search for this term while trying to view and copy their passwords.

Comment: That doesn't matter, they might find your question and see the linked one. (or they'll find this [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108242/how-does-nautilus-store-passwords-on-ubuntu))

Comment: Ye, I absolutely agree with that. Just not deleting it.